# How to stop timer affacted by button click?

Tags: c#, winforms

i am working on a winform application in which i have a timer.it is being used for showing stopwatch on the form. When i fire a button than my timer is interrupted. i want my timer to be uninterrupted while button is clicked. My code is as followed:-

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!_timerRunning)
    {
        // Set the start time to Now
        _startTime = DateTime.Now;

        // Store the total elapsed time so far
        _totalElapsedTime = _currentElapsedTime;

        _timer.Start();
        _timerRunning = true;
    }
    SqlConnection Con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=69.162.83.242,1232;Initial Catalog=test1;Uid=test;pwd=1234@Test;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;Connect TimeOut=60000;");
    //SqlConnection Con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=ADMIN-PC\\YASH;Initial Catalog=test;Integrated Security=True; Connect TimeOut=600");
    Con.Open();
    string messageMask = "{0} @ {1} : {2}";
    string message = string.Format(messageMask, label6.Text, DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString(), richTextBox2.Text);
    richTextBox1.AppendText(Environment.NewLine + message);
    SqlCommand cmd, cmd1;
    cmd = new SqlCommand("Update Chat set UserInitial=@message,Updated=1 where ExpertName ='" + label6.Text + "'", Con);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@message", message);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    Con.Close();
    richTextBox2.Text = String.Empty;
    richTextBox1.ScrollToCaret();
}

private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    richTextBox1.ScrollToCaret();
    count = count + 1;
    count1 = count1 + 1;
    timerSinceStartTime = new TimeSpan(timerSinceStartTime.Hours, timerSinceStartTime.Minutes, timerSinceStartTime.Seconds + 1);
    // The current elapsed time is the time since the start button was
    // clicked, plus the total time elapsed since the last reset
    _currentElapsedTime = timerSinceStartTime + _totalElapsedTime;

    // These are just two Label controls which display the current 
    // elapsed time and total elapsed time

    if (count1 == 180)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("You are Automaticlly hired by User");
        if (label7.Visible == true)
        {
            label7.Visible = false;
            count = 0;
            timerSinceStartTime = new TimeSpan(00, 00, 00);
            label3.Visible = true;
        }
    }
    label3.Text = timerSinceStartTime.ToString();


    // If we're running on the UI thread, we'll get here, and can safely update 
    // the label's text.


    richTextBox1.ScrollToCaret();
}
```

how to solve it??
thanks in Advance

Comment: Is it a `System.Windows.Forms.Timer`? If so try switching to a timer that supports threads like `System.Timers.Timer`.

Comment: but System.Timers.Timer is giving me cross threaded error. what about it?

Comment: Yes of course, you need to use `Control.Invoke()` when it comes to updating your form controls.

Comment: yes but it doesn't give me regular update after 1 second i think. i want my timer not to be stopped by any way

Comment: Sure it does. I use them all the time.

Comment: can u give me a running example? a timer stop watch doesn't affacted by button click...

Comment: that is what the Timer is supposed to do. You should try putting a Debug.Writeline in the timer event handler and see if its being called every second or not. Well it's not guaranteed to be exactly 1 second but at least one second

Comment: control.invoke is also not giving me satisfactory answer..Can u give me live example of it???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this,

```
private bool bStopTimer = true;
private void StartTimer()
{
    System.Threading.Thread thread = new System.Threading.Thread(new System.Threading.ThreadStart(this.ThreadTimer));
    thread.IsBackground = true;
    thread.Start();
}


private void ThreadTimer()
{
    while (bStopTimer)
    {
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000); //interval in millisecond
        lock(lblLabel.Text)
        {
            lblLable.Text = System.DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss");
        }
    }
}
```

**Update**

place this line before Application.Run(new frmForm);

```
System.Windows.Forms.Control.CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = false;
```

Comment: @user3346501 did you set the property System.Windows.Forms.Control.CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls to false?

Comment: your code is working fine now. But it doesn't give my answer. i want my timer uninterrupted but when i fire another button than it stops for around 2 seconds. i want my timer working perfectly.

Comment: May be your application hanged up in cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); line. You can use asynchronous method to execute your query. for example cmd.BeginExecuteNonQuery();

Comment: check this example from msdn http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7b6f9k7k(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: i agree with you. it is working fine after i removed my queries. but i have to run these queries on button click. what will be the procedure for it

Comment: As i have mentioned above you have to execute that query asynchronously using cmd.BeginExecuteNonQuery();

Answer (score 1):

Your problem stems from the fact you're using `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` which is not threaded and relies on the message pump. While your program is busy in the UI thread the message pump won't be processed.

You can improve this by moving to a timer that supports threads. I prefer `System.Timers.Timer` but there's also `System.Threading.Timer`.

With `System.Timers.Timer` the tick event is raised on a background thread if you don't pass any sync object in so that any code within the event handler will be handled in a separate thread.

Of course, to update the form we have to marshal back to the UI thread so we'll also need to use `Control.Invoke()`.

This is very rough, but something like this:

```
System.Timers.Timer timer = new System.Timers.Timer();  

timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OnTimer);
timer.Interval = 1000;
timer.AutoReset = false;
timer.Enabled = true;

public void OnTimer(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    // Do something busy like dancing

    // Update form
    Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate() {
        UpdateForm();
    });

    // Restart timer
    ((System.Timers.Timer)sender).Start();
}

public void UpdateForm()
{
   // Code to update the form
}
```

Note I use `AutoReset = false` so that if the tick event takes longer than the timer interval you won't get overlap. You may or may not want this it entirely depends on what you're doing.